# not valid category url rewrite in the same category name

Tags: catalog, url, magento-1, url-rewrite

I have the problem with category URL rewrites.

```
$category1 = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(2495);
$category2 = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(5966);
```

First output (not valid friendly url):

> http://www.my-website.com/catalog/category/view/s/category-name/id/2495/

Second output, total valid friendly url like:

> http://www.my-website.com/category-name

I would also like to mention that these categories has the same value in `catalog_category_entity_url_key`. Might it be the problem?
I executed URL redirects reindex and cleared cache. 
Do you have any ideas for this?

Answer (score 0):

**This issue is created due to indexing.**

### Solution:

- reindex magento using ssh so that indexing will do properly
- Save category from backend so that magento,call indexing for this particular  category.
- Check magento log ,if there have any issue during indexing and fix them

Comment: How to do with Default URL Rewrite Management for Main Category, is possible?

Comment: help me @ https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/219953/57334